# Blocking Apache POI While Creating XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache POI 3.7 in JDK 1.5 Environment and `-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=1000M` as JVM arguments.

I wrote the code to read xlsx file like this,

```
File file = new File("C:\\D\\Data Book.xlsx");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(inputStream);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

At the fourth line it is going into idle state. If I remove JVM arguments it is throwing `OutOfMemoryError`. My file size is 6MB.

Comment: How do you know it is in an idle state? Could it not still be processing?

Comment: Thanks for your response,Yes it is not proceeding. After sometime it is throwing OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: This indicates then that a) it is not idle and b) you need to allocate additional memory on top of what you have already specified.

Comment: But i hope the arguments which i am passing to JVM is more than enough to read 6 MB.

Comment: Just because the file is 6 MB on disk, it doesn't mean that the library requires an equally small amount of memory to load and process the file.

Answer (score 1):

If using `OPCPackage` is not essential then I would go for a straight instantiation:

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\D\\Data Book.xlsx");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
```

See the [POI Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook)

Comment: Thank you guys. I solved the issue by using apache POI's event API.
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file, then pass that in. Using an InputStream requires buffering of everything into memory, which eats up space. Since you don't need to do that buffering, don't!

If you're running with the latest nightly builds of POI, then it's very easy. Your code becomes:

```
File file = new File("C:\\D\\Data Book.xlsx");
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

Otherwise, it's very similar:

```
File file = new File("C:\\D\\Data Book.xlsx");
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file.getAbsolutePath());
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to believe that this question wasn't answered for almost 8 years.
I've posted the same answer to one of the similar questions, let me post it here as well.
Instead of XSSFWorkbook (which keeps the entire Excel workbook in memory) try to use very efficient and high performance streaming SXSSFWorkbook class like below:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
```

where 100 is the default number of rows that will be kept in memory and processed in real time.